# Mahalanobis Distance - Geometric Place

Tags: r, self-study, matlab, mahalanobis

Given a matrix $\mathbb{X}$ of 20 elements, representing 20 observation of a 5-variable normal, I was asked to find the Sample Mean Vector and Sample variance matrix and to find the geometric place of the points $\mathbb{R}^5$ such that the Mahalanobis distance of those points to the Sample Mean is 10. That is, I need to solve

$$ (\bar{X}-y)' S^{-1}(X) (\bar{X} - y) = 100 $$

for $y$.

Is there a way to output an equation using R or Matlab in function of the coordinates of $y$?

Comment: The equation you wrote is a function of the coordinates of $y$.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if I can construct a function that output this equation.

Comment: I mean, I need to find the geometric place, so shouldn't I find a equation?

Comment: The equation is written. What you need is to be able to describe its solution. I could give you the answer but I think it is more interesting for you to understand the question first. 
Let’ tackle a simple particular case first. Assume that, by chance, $S(X)$ is the identity matrix and $\overline X = 0$. Can you describe the place of $y'y = 100$?

Comment: Once you’ve answered that, I’ll ask you "what do you know about symmetric matrices like $S(X)$? Ever heard of the spectral theorem? Does "orthonormal basis of eigenvectors" ring a bell?". And I hope that you'll be able to find the answer by yourself at this point.

Comment: I believe a more conventional English description of "geometric place" would be "locus" or "solution set." There are two standard ways to describe such points: *implicitly*, which is the form given in the question (as the set of zeros of a function), and *parametrically* (as the image of a function defined on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$ in this case). Both types of solution can be simplified by the choice of coordinates: for instance, one might be tempted to use spherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^5$ to describe these points or even certain matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{25}$.

Comment: Or words, words, words. As a teacher, I would expect a sentence here.